# Parameterize Azure API Management backend

Tags: azure-api-management

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<set-backend-service base-url="https://{{context.Variables['instance']}}/api" />
```

Or

```
<set-backend-service backend-id="my-{{context.Variables['instance']}}-api"/>
```

But getting errors that I've given an invalid URL or that APIM can't locate that backend. Is there a way to parameterize your backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying is only applicable in [`liquid` templates when using the `set-body`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#using-liquid-templates-with-set-body) policy OR when using [Named Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-properties). In other scenarios, it has to be a [policy expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions).

Something like this can be done instead

```xml
<set-variable name="resource-group-name" value="rg-01" />
<set-variable name="logic-app-name" value="la-01" />
<set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="@("LogicApp_" + context.Variables["resource-group-name"] + "_" + context.Variables["logic-app-name"])" />
```

PS: The example above is for a Logic App backend created when importing one from the Portal UI.